# route problem not detected by the router and by the front

Tags: php, symfony, twig

My problem is the following, I am currently working with symfony 6 I want to create several controllers for my administration panel except that but route is not detected by the router or by the front (twig).
I tried cleaning cache, deleting my admin folder in controller folder, renaming but file (controller file).
I launched the command php bin/console debug:router but I do not see but route

This is a part of my controller :

```
 #[Route('/admin/user/all/', name: 'app_admin_users', methods: ['GET'])]
#[Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')")]
public function users(): Response
{
    $users = $this->userService->getAllUsers();
    return $this->render('admin/users/index.html.twig', [
        'users' => $users,
    ]);
}
```

This is route.yaml :

```
controllers:
resource: ../src/Controller/
type: annotation
```

kernel:
resource: ../src/Kernel.php
type: annotation

End this is my front error :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "app_admin_users" as such route does not exist.").
```

Comment: That extra space in front of the route attribute ` #[Route...` in your posted code is not actually there in your real code? And the users method is in a controller somewhere under `src/Controller'?  And you have a bunch of other attributed routes that show up just fine?

Answer (score 1):

When using attributes, route type in `route.yaml` should be configured as `type: attribute` .

Comment: when i but attribute to annotation place i get an error.    Cannot load resource "../src/Controller/". Make sure there is a loader supporting the "attribute" type.

Comment: I have about twenty controls which work without problems despite its being an annotation which is noted and not attribute.

Comment: @jeremielegrand Do you have `use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;` at the top of the controller's file?

Answer (score 1):

> (from comments)
> when i but attribute to annotation place i get an error. Cannot load
> resource "../src/Controller/". Make sure there is a loader supporting
> the "attribute" type

The Symfony documentation says: "The attribute value of the second argument of import() was introduced in Symfony 6.1".

Make sure your `symfony/routing` package is `6.1` or higher version

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33042175)